# do while loop in C: problem with while condition

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while

Okay, I feel really stupid and maybe I'm missing something, but I'm going through some materials from my college and there was a solved problem code about entering a number between [0, 10] (inclusive) and calculating out the factorial of the number.

The code from the materials:

> ```c
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main(void) {
>     int b, i;
>     int f = 1;
>
>     do {
>         printf("Input a number within a set [0, 10]: ");
>         scanf ("%d", &b);
>     } while (b < 0 || b > 10);
>
>     for (i = 2; i <= b; i++)
>         f *= 1;
>
>     printf("Factorial of the number %d (%d!) is: %d", f);
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Now, I want to note I'm really a beginner at all of this, but this didn't really look right, and when I ran it (in CodeBlocks) it showed an error.

Then I wanted to try writing out the code myself, but I have found myself struggling with the `do`-`while` loop, specifically with the condition for the `while` part of the loop.

I wanted to test the code out bit by bit, and this is what I've written:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int nmbr;
    int i;

    do {
        printf("Enter a number within the interval [0, 10]: \n");
        scanf("%d", &nmbr);
    } while (nmbr>= 0 && nmbr<= 10);

    printf("The number is: %d", nmbr);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, my question is, since `nmbr >= 0 && nmbr <= 10` literally means that `nmbr` is every number that is GREATER than or equal to zero AND LESS than or equal to 10 - meaning that is literally every number between zero and ten INCLUDING a zero and a ten, why is the code not working?

It works if I put `nmbr < 0 || nmbr > 10`, but that isn't right, is it?  How can it still include a zero or a ten when it's saying that it's every number strictly LESS than zero or strictly GREATER than 10? Am I missing something really obvious?

Overall, I was trying to get the input to be only between 0 and 10 (including the two), and I'm struggling with syntax I guess.

Comment: @GSerg, it seems inappropriate to reformat code that the OP is quoting from another source.  But if you insist on doing that, then did you have some objection to my edits that you clobbered?

Comment: @JohnBollinger It was in fact you who thwarted my editing attempt with your edit. (Isn't it annoying to get the "already edited" popup only to find that it was an incomplete edit that leaves the post in a half readable state when you were going to fix it all?) What is the reformatting of the quoted code you are referring to though? The fact that I added the quote block? I believe that is appropriate for a quote. Or that I added indentations? I believe the lack of indentation was due to the OP not knowing how to handle them rather than because this is how the lecture material wants it.

Comment: @GSerg, for what it's worth, my own first attempt at the edit was thwarted by the OP.  Yes, it is annoying, but it happens.  The reformatting I am talking about is that of the first program, which the OP says is *from the [course] materials*.  That is why I did not reformat that program myself.  I don't really care much about that, but it does seem to be the only thing you edited that I did not, whereas there are several other changes that I made but you did not.  It is these latter that I am asking you about.

Comment: `do { ... scanf("%d", &nmbr); } while (nmbr>= 0 && nmbr<= 10);` -> `for (;;) { ... if (scanf("%d", &nmbr) != 1) return 1; if (nmbr>= 0 && nmbr<= 10) break; }` and also `f *= 1;` -> `f *= i;`

Comment: @JohnBollinger Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75912659/revisions, I believe the only other difference is that you removed "Um", "literally" and "the hell", which I don't have a strong preference over but would have not thought to remove, but then again, you missed the `its` - but it's splitting hair now. I'm happy if you copy your language edits back.

Answer (score 1):

The loop will execute while the `nmbr` is between `0` and `10` inclusive. You want it to end. Also, it's `nmbr` not `nbmr`.

```
int nmbr;
int i;

do {
    printf("Enter a number within the interval [0, 10]: \n");
    scanf("%d", &nmbr); /* not nbmr */
} while (!(nmbr >= 0 && nmbr <= 10)); /* or, while (nmbr < 0 || nmbr > 10) */
printf("The number is: %d\n", nmbr);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the second loop is still going to perform what I want it to when it means that its strictly every number less than zero or strictly every number greater than zero? Shouldn't that mean that it won't include exactly the numbers that I need it to?

Comment: the return value of `scanf()` should be tested too

Comment: On what condition should the loop continue to execute? When the number is *outside* the desired interval.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop in the first code example prompts for and reads input from the user over and over until an acceptable input is read.  `b < 0 || b > 10` is the condition for performing another iteration of the loop.  That is, values of `b` that are either less than zero or greater than 10 are rejected, which is exactly what you say you want.

> Now, my question is, since `nmbr >= 0 && nmbr <= 10` literally means
> that `nmbr` is every number that is GREATER than or equal to zero AND
> LESS than or equal to 10 - meaning that is literally every number
> between zero and ten INCLUDING a zero and a ten, why is the code not
> working?

Because you have mistaken the sense of the test.  When the condition evaluates true, it means that another iteration of the loop should be performed, thus rejecting the current input.  The condition in the first code is appropriate for this.

> Am I missing something really obvious?

It seems so.  See above.

---

**Side note**: in the first code, this ...

> ```
>         f *= 1;
> ```

... is surely wrong.  It looks like an OCR or transcription error.  The intended code is undoubtedly

```
        f *= i;
```